# Average Rating per Post based on Comment Rating

Tags: custom-post-types, rating

I have created Custom Post Types.
In that i have a rating system in comments, for each comment user can rate 1-5 Stars.

Now , i want the average of all ratings in comments of that post to show.

How can i do that.

Here is the link to the code file related to My rating System. Current Users can rate and comment. But i want the average of all comment ratings in that post. And this is a custom Post type.

Please Help.

[I have Added the rating.php to my dropbox ][1]https://www.dropbox.com/s/a544cj13nji1jtb/templatic_post_rating.php

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question, rather than linking to your dropbox. Questions and especially answers are supposed to be useful long after the initial OP's issue has (hopefully) been resolved.

Comment: sorry , i will add the code on pastebin

Comment: this is the whole code which i use star rating in comments, currently users can rate each comment from 1-5 stars. basically i want to show the average of all the ratings in comments for that particular post. here is the link the codes http://pastebin.com/LcRyjSPK

Comment: How is a pastebin "including relevant code in the question"? That isn't much better than Dropbox. Edit the question, please.